# ¿Cómo traigo datos de otra tabla con inner join?

Tags: linq

tengo esta consulta y necesito traer de la tabla PAGO EMPLEADO la columna PAGO. pero no sé como hacerlo, intenté poniendo una " , " después del select i y no funcionó.

¿Algún genio? Perdón por el retraso.

```
        Model1 Entity = new Model1();

        var datos = (from i in Entity.EMPLEADO
                     join e in Entity.PAGO_EMPLEADO
                     on i.ID_EMPLEADO equals e.COD_EMPLEADO
                     where i.ESTADO == true && i.ID_EMPLEADO == e.COD_EMPLEADO
                     select i).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes especificar las columnas de la consulta:

Ejemplo:

```
Model1 Entity = new Model1();

var datos = (from i in Entity.EMPLEADO
             join e in Entity.PAGO_EMPLEADO
             on i.ID_EMPLEADO equals e.COD_EMPLEADO
             where i.ESTADO == true && i.ID_EMPLEADO == e.COD_EMPLEADO
             select new
             {
                e.PAGO
             }).ToList();
```

o según la descripción de tu pregunta, usa `e.PAGO` ya que `e` es la tabla `PAGO_EMPLEADO` de la cual quieres obtener la columna `PAGO`. Te sugiero cambiar los nombres de las variables por nombres mas claros.

Ejemplo:

En vez de:

`e.PAGO`

usa:

`_pagos.PAGO`

Para mas información [guíate de esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6370057/4092887).

Comment: Gracias, lo he solucionado!

Answer (score -2):

Antes del `from` coloca lo siguiente:

```
select campo1,campo2
```

Donde `campo1` y `campo2`, son los campos que deseo ver o si quieres verlos todos, sustituyes `campo1` y `campo2` por un asterisco (`*`), es decir `select *` y luego el `from`.